# Middleware laravel with UML

Tags: laravel, uml, middleware, representation

how can i represent Middleware classes with UML class diagram ?

my root file :

```
  route::group(['prefix'=>'member','middleware'=>'member'],function(){
          route::get('/','Dashboard@index');
});
 route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'admin'],function(){
          route::get('/','Dashboard@panel');
});
```

how can i represent relationship between my two middleware with my class "dashboard".